# Как быстро посчитать расстояния от одной точки до всех остальных точек?

Tags: python, геометрия

Есть куча точек X, заданных в n-мерном пространстве (пусть у нас будет двумерное, то есть рамерность массива X — *куча* x 2),
есть отдельная точка С в том же пространстве (рамерность 1х2)
и есть метрика dist(u,v), заданная над пространством, которая определяет расстояние между двумя точками (пусть у нас будет эвклидова метрика, dist() возвращает float).

Есть ли в чистом python или в numpy (или где-то ещё, чтоб подсмотреть) способ посчитать расстояния от С до всех точек Х, более быстрый, чем

```
[dst(x,C) for x in X]
```

?

А то банально очень долго в секундах получается.
В принципе, достаточно также получить только сумму этих расстояний, если это вдруг окажется легче.

Comment: Вряд ли. Разве что реализация dist на С. Поскольку расчёт зависит от метрики -- внешней функции dist. Но если вопрос касается не столько однократного расчёта, а многократных пересчётов, то так уже надо смотреть, что меняется при пересчётах.

Comment: Массив точек Х часто меняется, или статичен?

Comment: Массив Х статичен, меняется С.

Comment: Тогда (для dist(x, C) = sqrt((x.X-C.X)**2+(x.Y-C.Y)**2) приходит в голову реализация на Це с передачей X один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм оптимального подсчёта, безусловно, зависит от функции dist.
Потому что для каждой функции dist существует свой такой алгоритм.

Если рассматривать плоскость и еклидово расстояние, то очевидной оптимизацией будет заметить то, что dist(a, b) = dist(b, a). Поэтому обычный цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        a[i, j] = dist(dots[i], dots[j]);
```

Можно заменить на:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++){
        a[i, j] = dist(dots[i], dots[j]);
        a[j, i] = a[i, j];
    }
```

Очевидно, что самая затратная операция для вычисления евклидова расстояния - это корень. Но понятно, что его можно опустить (т.е. вычисления всех расстояний проводить без извлечения корня из суммы квадратов). Тогда свойства расстояний сохранятся (например, их тоже можно сравнивать и мы получим тот же результат, что и при вычислении корня).

Вообще, как я уже говорил, нужно исследовать функцию dist и попробовать оптимизировать её вычисление.

Comment: Причем здесь `dist(a,b)=dist(b,a)` если речь идёт о расстоянии от центра C? @bekabaka факторный анализ, автоматическая классификация?

Comment: Я расписал общий случай.

Comment: Спасибо, толково, но ответ не на мой вопрос. Я считаю не расстояния от каждой до каждой точки, а только расстояния от каждой до одной, поэтому симметричность метрики не помогает.
Насчёт того, что основная нагрузка это расчёт метрики — очень толково, корень из евклидового расстояния я уже выбросил. Но, к сожалению, прирост от этого не слишком заметный. Надеялся, что есть какой-то более эффективный цикл.

Comment: А это вся задача? Т.е. нужно просто придумать как это сделать быстрее? Или Вы решали какую-то другую задачу, которую свели к тому, что надо уметь быстро искать такие расстояния?

Answer (score 1):

Расстояние до сетки точек можно рассчитать с помощью матриц, как длину вектора в комплексных числах.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cmath

>>> a = np.array([[ 0.+0.j,  0.+1.j],[1.+0.j,  1.+1.j]], dtype=np.complex)
>>> a
    array([[ 0.+0.j,  0.+1.j],
           [ 1.+0.j,  1.+1.j]])

>>> n=0+0j

>>> L=a-n

>>> L
    array([[ 0.+0.j,  0.+1.j],
           [ 1.+0.j,  1.+1.j]])
>>> abs(L)
    array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ],
           [ 1.        ,  1.41421356]])





>>> n=0.5+0.5j
>>> n
   (0.5+0.5j)

>>> L=a-n

>>> abs(L)
    array([[ 0.70710678,  0.70710678],
           [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]])
```

Ниже приведен пример, рассчитывающий расстояния от четырех точек.

В каждой точке сетки суммируются синусы от расстояния, и получаем аналог сложения волн.

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cmath
razner=400

k=np.zeros((razner, razner), dtype=np.complex)

for kx in range (razner):
    for ky in range (razner):

        k[kx,ky]=kx+(ky)*1j       

L1=k-250-50*1j
L2=k-50-250*1j
L3=k-150-250*1j
L4=k-100-150*1j


Z =np.sin(0.1*np.abs((L4)))+
    np.sin(0.1*np.abs((L1)))+np.sin(0.1*np.abs((L2)))+np.sin(0.1*np.abs((L3)))


im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='bilinear', cmap=cm.RdYlGn,
               origin='lower', extent=[-3, 3, -3, 3],
               vmax=abs(Z).max(), vmin=-abs(Z).max())

plt.savefig("d:\V4.pdf")
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]